# proof verification on closed set

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $x_{0}\in X,\varepsilon >0$. Show that $A=\left \{ x\in X:d(x,x_{0})\leq \varepsilon  \right \}$ is closed.

**My solution:**
Let $f(x)=d(x,x_{0})$. Then $A=f^{-1}(-\infty ,\varepsilon ]$  and since $f$ is continuous and $(-\infty ,\varepsilon ]$ is closed then $A$ is closed.

Is my proof ok?

Comment: Isn't $A$ just an open ball centered at $x_0$, i.e. should it not be open and not closed?

Comment: Maybe you have a typo in the definition of $A$. I guess you want $\leq$ instead of $<$.

Comment: yes its <= sorry i will correct it

Comment: your proof is correct. Alternative you can also use the pre-image of $[0,\varepsilon]$. What makes you feel unsure?

Comment: i am not sure i have a full intuition about the A set  , what i mean .. and correct me if i am wrong , A is all the values where satisfy a condition , so A  can it be $A=\left \{ x_{1},x_{2} ,...,x_{n}\right \}$ or its $A=(a,b)or \left [ a,b \right ]$ ect ? so that confuses me and i was unsure about the way to prove it